# why windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessID can't find the function?

Tags: python

I'm reading *Black Hat Python* and in chapter 8 I find "user32.GetWindowThreadProcessID(hwnd,byref(pid))" doesn't work, just like the picture shows.

It seems that python can't find *GetWindowThreadProcessID*, but it can find *GetForegroundWindow* which also is exported from user32.dll.

I also try "windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")", but it still doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you your OS version is at least Windows 2000 Professional:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
pid = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
print( ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,ctypes.byref(pid)) )
```

Comment: Thank you, I have found the embarrassing problem that I mistakenly typed in "D" instead of "d" in "GetWindowThreadProcessId".